# laravel route nott defined

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

route: `web.php` routes definitions

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/home', 'AdminController@home');
    Route::get('/manage', 'AdminController@manage');
});
```

sidebar links routes is missing

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{route('admin.manage')}}" class="nav-link">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
        <p>Employees</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't named routes. Try this code.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {

    Route::get('/home', 'AdminController@home')->name('admin.home');

    Route::get('/manage', 'AdminController@manage')->name('admin.manage');
});
```

See also documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes

 You can also add `as` parameter in grouping

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function() {

    Route::get('/home', 'AdminController@home')->name('home');

    Route::get('/manage', 'AdminController@manage')->name('manage');
});
```

Comment: that case make my answer as acepted